# Prove that if $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers and $a+b+c = 1$ then $(3abc)^2 \ge (1-2a)(1-2b)(1-2c)(a^2+b^2+c^2).$

Tags: inequality

> Prove that if $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers and $a+b+c = 1$ then $(3abc)^2 \ge (1-2a)(1-2b)(1-2c)(a^2+b^2+c^2).$

Cauchy-Schwarz doesn't really help here and neither does rearrangement so I see nothing better to do than substitute: $$(1-2a)(1-2b)(1-2c)(a^2+b^2+c^2) = (2(b+c)-1)(2(a+c)-1)(2(a+b)-1)(a^2+b^2+c^2).$$ I get stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

We need to prove that 
$$9a^2b^2c^2\geq(a^2+b^2+c^2)(a+b-c)(a+c-b)(b+c-a)(a+b+c)$$
Let $a+b-c=z$, $a+c-b=y$ and $b+c-a=x$.

Since $\prod\limits_{cyc}(a+b-c)>0$, we can assume that $x$, $y$ and $z$ are non-negatives.

Indeed, let $x<0$ and $y<0$. Hence, $x+y<0$, which gives $c<0$. Contradiction.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$9(x+y)^2(x+z)^2(y+z)^2\geq32xyz(x+y+z)\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2+xy)$$
which is $\sum\limits_{sym}(9x^4y^2+9x^3y^3-7x^4yz-10x^3y^3z-x^2y^2z^2)\geq0$,
which is obvious by Muirhead.

Comment: What is $\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2+xy)$ in terms of variables?

Comment: $\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2+xy)=x^2+y^2+z^2+xy+xz+yz$

Comment: How does $\sum\limits_{sym}(9x^4y^2+9x^3y^3-7x^4yz-10x^3y^3z-x^2y^2z^2)\geq0$ follow from Muirhead?

Comment: Because $(4,2,0)\succ(4,1,1)$, $(4,2,0)\succ(3,2,1)$, $(3,3,0)\succ(3,2,1)$ and $(3,3,0)\succ(2,2,2)$.

Comment: I still don't see how it follows from those majorizations. Can you be more explicit?

Comment: You can read about Muirhead theorem. In our case  you can use also AM-GM for the proof of all steps. Good luck!